# Swap two objects in Realm.io database in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

In my App I store data in Realm database and display data in UITableView. I add cool feature at table - now I can swap cells by drag and drop. But now I have to add method to DataBase class to swap related objects.

I've figured out that Realm is unordered, so I thought about adding one more property: index. But consequently I should raise all logic about indexing items in datamodel(insert at index, remove at index, etc), it seems to me wrong approach.

Interesting is there common way to solve such problem?

Comment: noticed, that it perfectly works without any method to swap objects, have no idea why....

Comment: I think it's fine to have a property in your realm browser that describes the index (though I'd probably call it something more specific to avoid confusion).

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe I was afraid of it. Hoped that realm has a possibility to insert Item at index.

By the way, all worked only visually, after reload app table view becomes former....

Comment: As you said, it's unordered so you need to define the order. It's a pretty simple task to do, and you already seem to have an idea of how to do it.

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe Yes, you're right. Moreover it seems to me a pretty good task for brain muscle, and I was just lazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you could add an index to your object, we generally recommend adding another object class to your schema, which carries a list of the objects you want to order. Lists / to-many relations are ordered by default in Realm and offer you a convenient interface to move objects and modify the order in various other ways.

Comment: Really? It sounds like a magic! Unfortunately, I have checked out [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and haven't found simple example that could provide me to your idea. Can I just add another one property in `Item` class:   `let items = List<Item>()`? And it will be contain ordered array of all items? It seems to me too easy to be true...

Comment: No, you would need to add this list to a new class `ItemList`, which models one list of items.

Comment: Perfect! All is working flawlessly! Thank you so much. I'va added below in additional answer my Realm Database classes (just as sample), so could you check out it, maybe there are still some mistakes in using realm methods? @marius

Answer (score 1):

This is the code demonstration of using List class of Realm database. That's how I've realized it in my project. I simplified it for convinience. Big thanks to @marius for providing me to such graceful solution.

```
class Item: Object {
    number: Int
    name: String

    convenience init(number: Int, name: String) {
        self.number = number        
        self.name = name  
    }

class ItemsList: Object {
    var list = List<Item>()
}

class DataBase {
    static let realm = try! Realm()
    static var itemsList = ItemsList()
    static var numberOfItems: Int {
        return self.itemsList.list.count
    }

    class func addItemToDataBase(number: Int, name: String) {
        let item = Item(number: number, name: String)
        try! realm.write({
            realm.add(item)
            print("Success!")
        })
        itemsList.list.append(item)
    }
}
```