# Opening Realm hangs after implementing new object class

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

I wish to support rearranging a UITableView. I have seen other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307452/reorder-uicollectioview-items-using-realmswift-on-drag-and-drop?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323322/swap-two-objects-in-realm-io-database-in-swift), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112704/how-can-i-re-order-the-realm-table-using-tableview-in-swift) recommend using a another class to manage the realm objects. The only problem is as soon as I add the class I cannot successfully open a Realm.

```
import RealmSwift

class Data: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
}

// Adding this class causes issues
class DataList: Object {
    let list dataList = List<Data>()
}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here? When I attempt to open the Realm it just hangs: no error thrown.

Edit:
From the realm [doc](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) it says they should be declared as let.

Comment: It should be `var dataList = List<Data>()` and if you change or add new class, you should bump your Realm database `schemaVersion` or uninstall/reinstall app in your phone/simulator

Comment: Properties of type `List` should be declared using `let`, not `var`. The remainder of what @Tj3n said is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Tj3n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230311/tj3n) for the solution. Migrate your schema or reinstall the app fixes the issue. Here is some [doc](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations) on that.